# R factors in a loop to build full data frame

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to write a loop that performs anova and TukeyHSD on my data across 3 samples for each "Label". Label in this case is a metabolic pathway. Data that goes into it are the genes expressed in said metabolic pathway.

For the test data, I created a small df that reproduces my error. In my actual data, I'm hoping to do perform this across 2 factors (not just one) and I have thousands of more rows.

```
library(reshape2)
df<-melt(data.frame(sample1 = c(0,0,3,4,5,1),sample2 = c(1,0,0,4,5,0),sample3 = c(0,0,0,8,0,0),Label = c("TCA cycle", "TCA cycle","TCA cycle", "Glycolysis","Glycolysis","Glycolysis"),Gene = c("k1","k2","k3","k4","k5","k6")))
```

My approach (annotated the best way I can!):

```
fxn<-unique(df$Label) #create list
for (i in 1:length(fxn)){
if (!exists("data")){ #if the "data" dataframe does not exist, start here!
  depth<-aov(df$value[df$Label==fxn[i]]~df$variable[df$Label==fxn[i]]) #perform anova on my "df", gene values as a factor of samples (for each "fxn")
  hsd<-TukeyHSD(depth) #calculate tukeyHSD
  data<-as.data.frame(hsd$`df$variable[df$Label == fxn[i]]`) #grab dataframe of tukey HSD output
  data$Label<-fxn[i] #add in the Label name as a column (so it looks like my original df, but with TukeyHSD output for each pairwise comparison
  data<-as.data.frame(data) 
}
if (exists("data")){ #if "data" exists, do this:
    tmpdepth<-aov(df$value[df$Label==fxn[i]]~df$variable[df$Label==fxn[i]])
    tmphsd<-TukeyHSD(tmpdepth)
    tmpdata<-as.data.frame(tmphsd$`df$variable[df$Label == fxn[i]]`)
    tmpdata$Label<-fxn[i]
    tmpdata<-as.data.frame(tmpdata)
    data<-rbind(data,tmpdata) #combine with original data 
    data<-as.data.frame
    rm(tmpdata)
  }
}
```

I'd like my output to look like this:

```
                      diff       lwr      upr     p adj      Label
sample2-sample1 -0.3333333 -8.600189 7.933522 0.9916089 Glycolysis
sample3-sample1 -0.6666667 -8.933522 7.600189 0.9669963 Glycolysis
sample3-sample2 -0.3333333 -8.600189 7.933522 0.9916089 Glycolysis
```

but the Label column has all the factors that went into "fxn".

Errors:

```
Error in rep(xi, length.out = nvar) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'
```

Comment: I'm also wondering if I can use rbind.fill here instead of rbind. This would help make this loop more robust if there is missing data somewhere, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the second `data` in the last line before rm(tmpdata). It should be:
`data<-as.data.frame(data)`

I my implementation I changed your code as follows:

```
datav <- data.frame(diff = double(),
    lwr = double(),
    upr = double(),
    'p adj' = double(),
    'Label' = character())

for (fxn in unique(df$Label)){
    depth <- aov(df$value[df$Label==fxn] ~ df$variable[df$Label==fxn]) 
    hsd <- TukeyHSD(depth) 
    tmp <- as.data.frame(hsd$`df$variable[df$Label == fxn]`) 
    tmp$Label <- fxn 
    datav <- rbind(datav, tmp)
}
```

Initializing the data.frame before hand you do not need the if statement. Also `data` is a function in R, so I rename the variable data to datav.